# Does the “Torque-Induced Precession” of the two rotor blades cause the V-22 Osprey to tear itself apart

Tags: aircraft-physics, vibration

Concerning Bell Boeing V-22 Osprey Aircraft:

Does the “Torque-Induced Precession” of the two rotor -- 3-blade, propellers cause the V-22 Osprey to become unstable.

In the case of a helicopter the Earths gravity pulls on the aircraft hull up to the rotor assembly, rotor blade “dissymmetry of lift.”

Does the changing of the **two gyroscopes**, **tiltrotor**, cause “harmonic coupling” and or “mechanical resonance” - causing the aircraft to become unstable?

Comment: For this question, how does a tiltrotor differ from a non-tiltrotor two-rotor helicopter such as a Chinook?  How does it differ from a conventional twin-prop airplane?  (If it's about while the rotors are tilting, how does that differ from a Chinook or a twin changing pitch as a whole?)

Comment: "*Does the “Torque-Induced Precession” of the two rotor blades cause the V-22 Osprey to tear itself apart?*" Yes it does, all of the V-22 were destroyed because of that reason 

Comment: Please note, “The second property is precession. Let’s follow the definition carefully. It is important to understand the effect of precession when we consider gyros. If an external force is applied to change the direction of the rotor spin axis -the gyro resists the change and instead moves the force at right angles to the direction originally applied, this is precession. The rule of precession states that the gyro will precess at 90 degrees to the applies force.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtniROSrovs

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/V-22_concept.jpg

Please note,  If an external force is applied to change the direction of the rotor spin axis “Transmission Interconnect Shaft” the gyro resists the change and instead moves the force at right angles to the direction originally applied, this is precession.

Comment: How does a tiltrotor differ from a non-tiltrotor two-rotor helicopter such as a Chinook? How does it differ from a conventional twin-prop airplane? The answer is the  aircraft: angular momentum, structure and especially helicopters - stable center of gravity. Notice that the V-22 Osprey has two heavy engines relative to center of gravity.

Comment: Rotor blades are not rigidly attached to the rotor hub but via hinges which leave the blades freely move. There's no precession for a rotor rather a resonance between flapping and pitching movement. This is a well know phenomenon and that's why the blade control is 90° shifted in respect to the the blades.

Answer (score 1):

The rotors of the [V-22 Osprey](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) turn in opposite directions.  This cancels and gyropscopic precession effects on the aircraft as a whole, eliminating the need for a tail rotor.

One may imagine a significant stress on each individual nacelle while yawing.  Ospreys are know for "gear box issues" and their production run may be over.